# trace of wedge product and cyclic property

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, trace, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Surprisingly, while their are similar but more advanced questions on this site, I don't see any answers to the basic version I am asking herein.

If I am taking the trace of a wedge product of matrices, can I still use the cyclic property? For instance, is it true that
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A B \wedge C) 
= \operatorname{Tr}(B \wedge C A)
$$

Furthermore, is there a good way to think about the trace of a wedge product like there is for tensor product:
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A \otimes B) 
= \operatorname{Tr}(A) \operatorname{Tr}(B)?
$$

Comment: What is a wedge product of matrices? I know of the exterior power of a linear transformation, but not of a wedge product between two different linear transformations.

Comment: Are you referring to the [box product](https://youtu.be/bb0nYuRABwc)?

Comment: To be honest, I am not entirely sure. I am looking at derivation of equation (115) in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.05230). There the derivative is applied to both sides of matrix wedge product before manipulating. You can also find equation in my other recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754963/exterior-derivative-of-the-wedge-product-of-matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems reasonable that the matrices $A, B, C$ are matrices with entries that are forms, and $A\wedge B$ is just matrix multiplication where we use $\wedge$ for the product. In this case "$AB\wedge C$" makes no sense unless $A$ is a matrix of 0-forms and we're omitting the wedge because it's the same as scalar multiplication in this case. I believe this is the case in the equations you linked to.

A simple computation in components will show
$$
  \mathrm{Tr}(B\wedge C) = B_{ij}\wedge C_{ji} = (-1)^{pq}C_{ji}\wedge B_{ij} = (-1)^{pq}\mathrm{Tr}(C\wedge B)
$$
where I've assumed $B$ is made up of $p$-forms and $C$ of $q$-forms. Since we're assuming that $A$ is made up of 0-forms, the equation you want does indeed hold.

Comment: Nicholas, thank you for the answer. I'd like to make sure I understand what you mean by "is just matrix mult. where we use $\wedge$ for the product". You are saying that the matrix is multiplied using matrix multiplication. Thus, the product will be a new matrix where elements of the that matrix will be sum of wedged products along common indices. I believe this is also what simple computation you provided shows. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @EEH Yes, that is what I was assuming.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think I will finally be able to complete the simplification in the paper!